Reed and Simon Chapter IX problem 45 (a): Multiplication by a regular but not smooth function in a negative local Sobolev space
I suppose you could see this as a spiritual follow-up to Multiplication by a regular function in a negative Sobolev space seen as an adjoint, hence the very similar choice of title and the very beginning being copy-pasted.
I'm trying once again to understand a statement by Reed and Simon in Volume II of their Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, section IX.6: Elliptic regularity.
They denote by $W_m$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$, the $m$-th Sobolev space which would be nowadays called $H^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$, defined as the set of tempered distributions $T$ whose Fourier transform $\widehat{T}$ is a measurable function satisfying:
$$\|T\|^2_{W_m} := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(1 + |\lambda|^2\right)^m |\widehat{T}(\lambda)|^2 \mathrm{d}\lambda < \infty$$
I also understand fairly well how they identify $W_{-m}$ to $W_m^*$ via the following isometric isomorphism: $$T \in W_{-m} \quad\longmapsto\quad \Lambda_T := \left(S \in W_m \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{T}(-\lambda) \widehat{S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda\right)$$
Now, they also define $W_m(\Omega)$ the $m$-th local Sobolev space of a given open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ as being the set of distributions $T \in \mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi T \in W_m$ for all smooth compactly supported functions $\varphi$ whose support lies in $\Omega$.
Problem $45.(a)$ (which, along most problems from this series of books, is not given a correction) then asks the following:

Prove that if $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and $V \in \mathcal{C}^m(\Omega)$ [$m$ is a non-negative integer, and $m$ can be as low as $0$ if I understand correctly], $u \in W^k(\Omega)$, $k \leq m$, then $Vu \in W_k(\Omega)$.

It's simple enough for $0 \leq k \leq m$ thanks to a quick Leibniz rule argument and the fact that all the partial derivatives $\partial^\alpha (\varphi V)$, $|\alpha| \leq m$, are bounded thanks to the assumptions on the $\varphi$s from the definition of $W_k(\Omega)$, and the case $-m \leq k \leq 0$ is then achievable using the duality $W_k = W_{-k}^*$ mentioned above and explored in the aforementioned prequel to this post, given that $V\psi$, $\psi$ smooth compactly supported, will belong to $H^{|k|}$.
The issue is then the case where $k \leq -m-1$, as I fear I need to be able to handle that situation as well in question $(b)$ which asks to show the local regularity of weak solutions of a Schrödinger equation on $\Omega$ of the type $(-\Delta + V - E)u = 0$, $E \in \mathbb{C}$, because the starting argument should be that, as a distribution, and since $\Omega$ is bounded, $u \in W_k(\Omega)$ for some undisclosed $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
However, in this case, we can no longer multiply $\psi$ smooth compactly supported by $V$ as it won't be guaranteed to lie in $H^{|k|}$ anymore, only in $H^m$, and I'm thus unsure at this point of how to show that $Vu$ will be well-defined in the first place, let alone belong in $W_k(\Omega)$.

I feel like this might be a mistake in the book, since it is indeed not clear how to even define $Vu$. For example, if $u=\partial_1 \delta$, i.e., the first partial derivative of the dirac delta distribution and $\Omega=B_1(0)$, then $u \in W_k(\Omega)$ for $k<-(n+1)/2$. However, if $V$ is just continuous and not differentiable in $0$, then $\langle Vu, \phi \rangle = -\partial_1 (V\phi)(0)$ makes no sense. Also, what is a weak solution if $Vu$ is not well-defined?

@Hidde I see. I'll still leave the question open in case someone else has other ideas about this, but if you turn this into an answer and there's no better answer by the end of the bounty period then I'll give you the bounty, because it's a satisfying enough explanation for me. But you're not obligated to do so by any means.

Let me turn my comment into an answer. I suspect that the exercise is incorrect, since it is not clear how to even define $uV$ if $u \in W_{-k}(\Omega)$ and $V \in \mathcal{C}^m(\Omega)$ with $k > m$. Indeed, by definition $u$ can only be applied to functions in $W_k$ multiplied by functions in $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. However, even for $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ we do not have that $V\varphi \in W_k$. Therefore, the following
$$
\langle Vu, \varphi \rangle := \langle u, V\varphi\rangle,
$$
is not well-defined. To illustrate this, one can simply take the first partial derivative of the dirac delta function $u=\partial_1 \delta$, which lies in $W_{-k}$ for $k>(n+1)/2$ since $\widehat{u}(\lambda)=2\pi i\lambda_1$. Then, with $\Omega=B_1(0)$, $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $V \in \mathcal{C}^0(\Omega)$ which is not differentiable in $0$, we formally find
$$
\langle Vu, \varphi \rangle =\langle \partial_1 \delta, V\varphi \rangle = -\partial_1 (V\varphi)(0),
$$
which does not make sense.
Regarding the exercise, since $Vu$ does not make sense, part (a) should include the assumption $|k| \leq m$ in (a). Furthermore, for part (b), I think one should assume that the weak solution lies in $W_{-m}(\Omega)$ at least, since otherwise the equation is not even well-defined. Then, using the regularity of the Laplacian repeatedly, one can obtain that $u \in W_{m+2}(\Omega)$ which embeds into $\mathcal{C}^l(\Omega)$ for $l < m+2-n/2$.
